# How can I add a where clause to a right outer join union left outer join?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, right-join

I'm using the following SQL and was wondering how and where I can put a where clause. So that I can for example bring all the results where id=2?

```
SELECT * 
FROM public_tips 
LEFT OUTER JOIN likes
USING (id) 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM likes 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN public_tips
USING (id)
```

I have tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM public_tips WHERE id=2
LEFT OUTER JOIN likes
USING (id) 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM likes WHERE id=2
RIGHT OUTER JOIN public_tips
USING (id)
```

but I get a syntax error!

Comment: where comes after from clause and join clause(s)

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause goes after the `from` clause, and the `join` clauses are part of the `from` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM public_tips
LEFT OUTER JOIN likes
USING (id) 
WHERE public_tips.id=2
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM likes 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN public_tips
USING (id)
WHERE public_tips.id=2
```

Comment: Is it possible to select* from public tips where id=2 and then count likes.column_name where id=2 in a single query?